# How to escape brackets for grep in shell script

Tags: grep, ksh

I have the line below in a script, and it doesn't work properly:

```
log_error_not_loaded=$(
    grep -e " ([^0]|[0-9]{2,}) Rows not loaded" ./my_file_name
)
```

However, when I execute the line by itself, outside of the script, it works (outputs the lines):

```
grep -e " ([^0]|[0-9]{2,}) Rows not loaded" ./my_file_name
```

From other tests I've run, I believe it's the `[]` and `{}` causing issues. Typical \ escape does not work.

Comment: any reason you're not using single-quotes instead of dbl-quotes? Single quotes will eliminate one class of problem (can't be certain it will fix it) Good luck.

Comment: Can you change your grep into `log_error_not_loaded=$(grep  " Rows not loaded" ./my_file_name)`

Comment: @shellter - single quotes don't help

Comment: @wallter-a, sqlldr log still returns "0 rows not loaded" when successful, so it would detect error on a successful run

Comment: You can pipe the result of the first grep (`0 rows not loaded`) into a `grep -v`, you just have to find out the character before the grep (space or start of line `^`). Or invert your logic, the script only works when you find a line `0 rows not loaded`.

Answer (score 0):

I just needed to escape the pipe, parentheses and curly braces:

```
log_error_not_loaded=$(
    grep -e " \([^0]\|[0-9]\{2,\}\) Rows not loaded" ./my_file_name
)
```

Comment: No, you needed to give grep the `-E` arg to tell it to use EREs instead of BREs.